# Overnight at Schiphol airport or hotel needed?

Tags: airport-transfer, hotels, sleeping, ams

I will go from Belgium (Brussels Midi Railway Station) to Netherlands (Schiphol airport) so I am supposed to arrive there on Saturday at 11:24pm and then wait like 10h for my next flight which takes place on Sunday at 12:30pm but I am not allowed to do the check-in until 9:30am.

So, I'd like to know if I would need to book a hotel or (if not) how "rude" is to sleep at Schiphol airport. For sure this is different from airport to airport and I was thinking to probably follow [this](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/amsterdam-airport-guide.htm) but I am not sure.

However, if booking a hotel is needed, I thought about getting a room at [Mercure](http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-1730-mercure-hotel-schiphol-terminal/index.shtml) (inside the airport) but I am not sure if I will be allowed to get inside since I won't be in transit/boarding area until 9:30am - Is that possible?

On the other hand, if that's not the right hotel, which one could fit better from the following [list](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/hotels/amsterdam-airport-hotels.htm) of hotels available at Schiphol for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleeping in airports is not uncommon when transiting through.  Quite a few people stretch out and nap while waiting their next flight.  But this is primarily in the transit areas, security often frowns on folks sleeping in the public area around the check in counters (otherwise homeless folks would flock to the heated airport lobbies armed with a second hand suitcase).

Both the Mecure Schipol and Yotel are inside the international transit area, so you can't access them until you check in for your flight.  The Yotel was closed last September during renovation, not sure if it has reopened yet.

The best bet is to book one of the other three on that website, since they are all within walking distance.  Or look on a booking website like Agoda and pick a hotel that offers free airport shuttles.

Comment: *"The Yotel was closed last September during renovation, not sure if it has reopened yet."* - [It hasn't](https://www.yotel.com/en/hotels/amsterdam-schiphol-hotel). As a matter of fact, the re-opening date has just moved from August to end September.

Comment: Agree to this. You would have to wait until your check-in opens. This depends on the airline and flight but this is usually 5 to 3 hours before the scheduled departure time. If I would be in your position, I would switch trains on Schiphol Airport train station and take the train back to Hoofddorp. That's only 4 minutes. From there you'll find several decent hotels on walking distance including Novotel and Hampton by Hilton.